# Is there an equivalent of Javascript's Array.map in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

Is there an equivalent of Javascript's `Array.map` in Java?

I have been playing with Java 8 :

```
List<Long> roleList = siteServiceList.stream()
        .map(s -> s.getRoleIdList()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but this doesn't work I don't know why the warning says `Incompatible Type`.

How can I do this in Java8?

Comment: Define "this doesn't work". Post all the relevant code, and the exact and complete error you get. Error messages are important.

Comment: Does it work with `List<List<Long>>` instead?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If `roleIdList` is a `List<Long>` and you want to get a `List<Long>` you have to use [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-) instead :

```
List<Long> roleList = siteServiceList.stream()
                .flatMap(s -> s.getRoleIdList().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you insist using `map` the return type should be `List<List<Long>>` :

```
List<List<Long>> roleList = siteServiceList.stream()
    .map(MyObject::getRoleIdList)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```